# 'too many open files' .A proxy service runs successfully when log4j level is 'DEBUG' and failed when log4j level is 'INFO' on WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: wso2, log4j

It's a strange problem.
when i set log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=DEBUG ,all is well.
when change to log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=INFO,the same proxy service failed.
here's my configuration：
[batchLoadDiagProxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgtUN.png)

[singleLoadDiagProxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ms9K.png)

when log level is INFO,i get ERRORs:

> [2018-09-19 09:18:50,242] [EI-Core]  WARN - PassThroughHttpListener System may be unstable: HTTP ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : too many open files java.io.IOException: too many open files
>   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
>
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
>
> at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:170)
>
> at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:153)
>
> at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:349)
>
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager$1.run(PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager.java:506)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> [2018-09-19 09:18:50,271] [EI-Core] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: I/O reactor has been shut down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening a command line and typing as a super user:
ulimit -f 100000
This will delay the error, but will not eliminate it.  The problem is that INFO outputs more data into *different files*. Each file handle is not closed before the next is opened; meaning the OS runs out of file handles quite quickly.

**Only** enable INFO when necessary for debugging.